# How to pass hyper link value via <display:table> <display:column> tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

Via Iterator I was able to pass hyper link value in my action class where it was used to update and delete, but `href` is not working inside `display:table` `display:column` tag. How to pass value via hyperlink in display table, and also how to put image?

**Working Iterator Code :**

```jsp
<s:iterator value=" #request.hrlist" >

<td><s:property value="Employement_detail"/></td>
<td><s:property value="Leaves_details"/></td>
<td><a href="editHyper?value=<s:property value="Employee_id"/>"><img src="img/edit.png" height="18" width="18" "></a></td>
<td><a href="delete?value=<s:property value="Employee_id"/>"><img src="img/delete.png" height="18" width="18" onclick="return myFunction()"></a></td>

</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two columns to the `display:table` one for the edit and another for the delete URLs. Also add `uid="row"` attribute to the tag.

```jsp
<s:url var="editUrl" action="editHyper">
  <s:param name="Employee_id" value="%{#attr.row.Employee_id}" />
</s:url>

<s:url var="deleteUrl" action="delete">
  <s:param name="Employee_id" value="%{#attr.row.Employee_id}" />
</s:url>

<display:column title="Edit">
  <s:a href="%{#editUrl}">Edit</s:a>
</display:column>

<display:column title="Delete">
  <s:a href="%{#deleteUrl}">Delete</s:a>
</display:column>
```

A complete example you can find here: [Pagination in Struts 2 Using display tag](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/pagination-example-in-struts-2/).

Comment: will it be same way for adding js and image,  the core code is pasted under second post of "I found that" heading, but that is different way i did this, please suggest me that your works for calling js and attaching image.

Comment: Just add `<img src=` to the anchor tag or use CSS, everything you can find in the links, also in my previous answers ;)

Comment: you should also upvote the answer that helped you and helped a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

I found it

```
<display:column property="employeeId" title="Update" href="editHyper" paramId="value" paramProperty="employeeId" />

<display:column property="employeeId" title="Delete" href="delete" paramId="value" paramProperty="employeeId" >
```